# WPF DataGrid with IEditableObject what user actions cancel edit mode

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

Once the edit cursor enters the cell, is there some default action that should cancel the edit, or do I need trap keypresses in code (like escape) to call DataGrid.CancelEdit()?